# Nodejs stop running when i close my Putty's session

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs to run on Ubuntu. However, i'm using Putty (i'm a windows user) to connect to the server.

The apps runs fine, the only problem that i have that as soon as i close Putty (Session), so does the nodejs stop running.

Is there any specific command should i run instead '**node server.js**' ?
Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Start it as a service.

Comment: There is multiple possibilties. For example, you can use a service, a deamon, like PM2, or start it in a [Screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen).

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this situation very efficiently by installing [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/).

> PM2 is a daemon process manager that will help you manage and keep
> your application online 24/7

#### Installation

The latest PM2 version is installable with NPM or Yarn:

```
$ npm install pm2@latest -g
// or 
$ yarn global add pm2
```

##### Start an app in background

The simplest way to start, daemonize and monitor your application is by using this command line:

```
$ pm2 start app.js
```

Once you've done this, you can simply close your putty session and your NodeJS server will keep running as a daemon in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Start your app as a service.

For that create a systemd unit file under `/lib/systemd/system/my-app.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=my-app description
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /opt/.../index.js
Restart=always
#User=nobody
# Note Debian/Ubuntu uses 'nogroup', RHEL/Fedora uses 'nobody'
# Group=nogroup
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/opt/.../

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then tell systemd to detect the new service `systemctl daemon-reload`.
After that enable & start your service:

```bash
systemctl enable my-app
systemctl start my-app
```

Then it starts automatically after a reboot & keeps running if you logout.